# The method isPriemtweeling() is undefined for the type MijnGetallen

Tags: java

When testing the domain class, I always get an error regarding the method 'IsPriemtweeling'.

Why isn't this code working?
Error message: The method isPriemtweeling() is undefined for the type MijnGetallen.

Thank you in advance!

Exercise

The domain class MijnGetallen

attributes: getal1, getal2

methods:

constructor

getters

setters:check at setGetal1 and setGetal2: number must be positive, if not the attribute is set to the default value 1

isPriemTweeling This method checks if the two attributes are prime numbers and if the difference between the two numbers is 2. Only then the method returns a true. To check if one of the attributes is a prime number, you can use an auxiliary method isPriem.

isPriem This method only returns true if the parameter it receives is a prime number. Note: 1 is not a prime number!

my development

```
package domein;

public class MijnGetallen {
    private int getal1, getal2;
    
    public MijnGetallen(int getal1, int getal2) {
        setGetal1(getal1);
        setGetal2(getal2);
    }
    
    public void setGetal1(int getal1) {
        if (getal1 >= 0) {
            this.getal1 = getal1;
        } else {
            this.getal1 = 1;
        }
    }
    
    public void setGetal2(int getal2) {
        if (getal2 >= 0) {
            this.getal2 = getal2;
        } else {
            this.getal2 = 1;
        }
    }
    
    public int getGetal1() {
        return getal1;
    }
    
    public int getGetal2() {
        return getal2;
    }
    
    public static boolean isPriem(int getal) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= getal / 2; i++) {
            if (getal % i == 0 || getal % (i + 2) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean isPriemTweeling() {
        if (isPriem(getal1) == true && isPriem(getal2) == true) {
            if (getal2 - getal1 == 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}  


Error message: The method isPriemtweeling() is undefined for the type MijnGetallen.
```

Comment: Case is significant in Java. you are calling isPriemtweeling but the class has isPriemTweeling

Comment: Yes! That was the problem!